# Javascript onload function alternative

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Hey guys I'm trying to integrate payment gateway in my website so they have send me a code but I'm quite new to javascript now they have send code working with `<body>` tag and I want to use this code with `<div>` tag:-

```
<script>
    var hash = '<?php echo $hash ?>';
    function submitPayuForm() {
      if(hash == '') {
        return;
      }
      var payuForm = document.forms.payuForm;
      payuForm.submit();
    }
  </script>
```

executing function like this:-

```
<body onload="submitPayuForm()">
```

How does it possible with or something else.

```
<div onload="submitPayuForm()">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Div Onload Custom Script by JQuery

```js
    var hash = '<?php echo $hash ?>';
    function submitPayuForm() {
      if(hash == '') {
        return;
      }
      //alert('here');
      //return false;
      var payuForm = document.forms.payuForm;
      payuForm.submit();
    }

$(function(){
  $('div[onload]').trigger('onload');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div onload="submitPayuForm()">
```

Comment: welcome@parthpurohit .. :)

Comment: actually i don't know how to add as useful

Comment: can you just call me on 7016490842 i have one more issue i can pay for it if you can help me..

Comment: if you want to add as usefull flag then just click on ^ arrow on top of the answer .

Comment: i have already did it.